# How to fix `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `T`?

Tags: frame, maxencodedlen, kitties-tutorial

When building my pallet, I run into the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:42:15
   |
42 |     #[pallet::pallet]
   |               ^^^^^^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `T`
   |
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` for `Kitty<T>`
  --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:25:69
   |
25 |     #[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
   |                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
26 |     #[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
27 |     pub struct Kitty<T: Config> {
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `StorageInfoTrait` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageKitties<T>, frame_support::Twox64Concat, <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash, Kitty<T>>`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `MaxEncodedLen` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
42 |     #[pallet::pallet + parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen]
   |                      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `pallet-template` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

The custom type definitions are:

```
// Struct for holding Kitty information.
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
pub struct Kitty<T: Config> {
    pub dna: [u8; 16],   // Using 16 bytes to represent a kitty DNA
    pub price: Option<BalanceOf<T>>,
    pub gender: Gender,
    pub owner: AccountOf<T>,
}

// Enum declaration for Gender.
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub enum Gender {
    Male,
    Female,
}
```

As far as I know, `MaxEncodedLen` should work for `Kitty` since all of its fields are also bounded in length.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11):

The underlying issue here is that Rust macros are not super intelligent.

While you are correct that all the interior fields of `Kitty` is bounded in length, you are also using the generic type `T: Config` to help access some of those types.

The Rust macros for automatically deriving `MaxEncodedLen` naively thinks that `T` must also be bounded by `MaxEncodedLen`, even though `T` itself is not being used in the actual types.

We can fix this in one of two ways:

1. Add a simple "hint" to the compiler in the form of `#[codec(mel_bound())]`.

   ```
   // Struct for holding Kitty information.
   #[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
   #[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
   #[codec(mel_bound())] // <---------------- Here
   pub struct Kitty<T: Config> {
       pub dna: [u8; 16],   // Using 16 bytes to represent a kitty DNA
       pub price: Option<BalanceOf<T>>,
       pub gender: Gender,
       pub owner: AccountOf<T>,
   }
   ```

   Oversimplifying, this will allow the compiler to skip trying to derive `MaxEncodedLen` for T, and just check the underlying types themselves all have `MaxEncodedLen`.
2. Do not use `<T: Config>` when defining `Kitties`.

   Instead, make generic only the types you need:

   ```
   // Struct for holding Kitty information.
   #[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
   pub struct Kitty<Account, Balance> {
       pub dna: [u8; 16],   // Using 16 bytes to represent a kitty DNA
       pub price: Option<Balance>,
       pub gender: Gender,
       pub owner: Account,
   }
   ```

   In this case, we have been able to remove `T` completely from the struct definition, and thus will have no complaints from the derive macro about trying to implement `MaxEncodedLen` for it. Note that we were also able to get rid of `#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]` from the definition aswell, since this basically doing the same thing as `#[codec(mel_bound())]` above.

Comment: That's a great explanation. I guess this must be in the tutorial as well.

Comment: I was searching substrate crates to get more information around mel_bound(). Can you throw some document pointers to #[codec(mel_bound())]?

Answer (score 1):

In case of a struct that has `Vec`:

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, TypeInfo)]
    pub struct Nickname {
        pub first: Vec<u8>,
        pub last: Option<Vec<u8>>, // handles empty storage
}
```

I found as a solution to use the macro `#[pallet::without_storage_info]`, this macro enables you to define pallet storage items that don't have a fixed size. This allows you to override the default behavior if you require unbounded storage for an entire pallet. To use it, add the `#[pallet::without_storage_info]` attribute to the pallet struct like so:

```
#[pallet::pallet]
#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
#[pallet::without_storage_info]
pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
```

I am posting this response in case it can be helpful to someone, but to store a Vec type is not the best practice, as it has no limit.

So in the case of haveing a Vec field, a better solution would be to come up with a size limit field (probably configured through your Config trait) and with it use `BoundedVec` instead of `Vec`:

```
pub struct Nickname<T: Config> {
    pub first: BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxLength>,
    pub last: Option<BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxLength>>,
}
```

And then use the solution Shawn proposed above.