# What is the role of `#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]`?

Tags: runtime, scale-codec, macro

```
#[derive(Encode,Decode,TypeInfo)
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
Pub struct Asset<T:Config> {
  Id:###
  Name:##
}
```

So in the above example if you don't include the second macro. The compiler will yell at you that typeinfo is not implemented in type `T`.
But if you include the macro it compiles fine.
So what does the macro do to the struct and how does it tackle the issue?

Comment: https://paritytech.github.io/ink/scale_info/index.html#scale_infoskip_type_params gives a pretty good overview.

Comment: @Squirrel the link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this question is similar to the answer here:

[How to fix `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `T`?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-to-fix-parity-scale-codecmaxencodedlen-is-not-implemented-for-t/620#620)

Basically, Rust macros are not that intelligent. In the case of the `TypeInfo` derive macro, we parse the underlying object, and try to turn it into some JSON expressed type which can be put in the metadata and used by front-ends.

While this type is generic over `<T: Config>`, we don't actually want to (or need to) include this information in the `TypeInfo` generation. This is really a Rust generic bound, so it does not make sense to include it in this context.

However, the macro does not know that, so we have `#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]` to be able to tell the macro to simply skip this when generating the `TypeInfo`, and that makes everything work.

Comment: While this answer does make sense I have a follow up question, why not entirely skip trait bounds by default when deriving `TypeInfo`? Are there cases where we actually need this ?

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that the purpose of [`DebugNoBound`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/derive.DebugNoBound.html), `CloneNoBound` and similar derive macros is similar: If the deriving type is generic over `T: Config`, these derives can be used other than the default ones.

See the full list of such derives [by searching `NoBound` in the substrate rust-docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/index.html?search=NoBound).