# Trait bond Clone not satisfied by pallet constant

Tags: pallet, trait

Trying to implement boundedVecs for an struct, but the compiler is telling me that I can´t Clone the struct because the StringLimit Constant doesn´t comply with the Clone Trait.

This is the definition of the constant under Config:

```
#[pallet::constant]
type StringLimit: Get<u32>;
```

And the following is the definition of the struct:

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, Eq, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(StringLimit))]
pub struct Details<Balance, AccountId, AssetId, BlockNumber, PollIndex, StringLimit: Get<u32>> {
    /// Poll id.
    pub poll_id: PollIndex,
    /// Account who created this poll.
    pub created_by: AccountId,
    /// Question for the poll.
    pub poll_question: BoundedVec<u8, StringLimit>,
    /// Option for the poll.
    pub poll_option_1: BoundedVec<u8, StringLimit>,
    /// Option for the poll.
    pub poll_option_2: BoundedVec<u8, StringLimit>,
    /// Option for the poll.
    pub poll_option_3: Option<BoundedVec<u8, StringLimit>>,
    /// Option for the poll.
    pub poll_option_4: Option<BoundedVec<u8, StringLimit>>,
    /// The number of poll options.
    pub options_count: u8,
    /// Info regrading stake on poll options.
    pub votes: Votes,
    /// Number of vote received.
    pub votes_count: u128,
    /// Currency of the poll.
    pub currency: AssetId,
    /// Status of the poll.
    pub status: PollStatus<BlockNumber>,
    /// Min balance to be able to vote on a poll.
    pub min_balance: Balance,
}
```

To make the code compile I needed to add Clone to the definition: type StringLimit: Get + Clone;

And to derive the trait at runtime level for the constant. I know that is not the correct solution. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: A little bit similar to https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/what-is-the-role-of-scale-infoskip-type-paramst/8812#8812

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`CloneNoBound`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/derive.CloneNoBound.html) that will not impose the `Clone` bound on the generic types. One example is here in [Cumulus](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/e046aba4ea8cee29a357d6aafa5904c093a9a261/cumulus/bridges/bin/runtime-common/src/refund_relayer_extension.rs#L240).
There are a few more of these kind such as `DefaultNoBound`, `EqNoBound`, `PartialEqNoBound` and `RuntimeDebugNoBound`.

Comment: It worked with CloneNoBound, but i had to add Clone trait bond to almost every other type, like the following: #[derive(CloneNoBound, Encode, Decode, Eq, PartialEq, Debug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(StringLimit))]
pub struct PollDetails<Balance: Clone, AccountId: Clone, AssetId: Clone, BlockNumber: Clone, PollIndex: Clone, StringLimit: Get<u32>> {  ... Is that right?

Comment: Yep, since the other types actually need to be clonable.