# error[E0277]: the trait bound `LabelInfo<T>: parity_scale_codec::Decode` is not satisfied

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot

i wanna to create pallet in substrate . i faced this error . how can i solve this problem ?

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

/// Edit this file to define custom logic or remove it if it is not needed.
/// Learn more about FRAME and the core library of Substrate FRAME pallets:
/// <https://docs.substrate.io/reference/frame-pallets/>
use codec::alloc::vec;
use frame_support::{
    inherent::Vec,
    pallet_prelude::{ValueQuery, *},
    sp_runtime::{
        traits::{AccountIdConversion, AtLeast32BitUnsigned, CheckedAdd, Hash, Member, One},
        DispatchError, SaturatedConversion,
    },
    traits::{ExistenceRequirement, Get, ReservableCurrency},
    transactional, PalletId, Twox64Concat,
};
use frame_system::Config as SystemConfig;
pub use pallet::*;
use sp_runtime::traits::UniqueSaturatedFrom;

#[cfg(test)]
mod mock;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests;

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
mod benchmarking;

mod functions;
mod structs;
mod types;

use structs::labels::Labels::RegisterInputLabelInfo;
use types::types::Types::{
    AccountOf, ArtistInfo, ArtistInfoDetail, BalanceOf, HashId, LabelsDetail,
};

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {

    use super::*;

    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;

    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;
        type Currency: ReservableCurrency<Self::AccountId>;

        #[pallet::constant]
        type StackLimit: Get<u32>;

        #[pallet::constant]
        type PalletId: Get<PalletId>;
    }

    
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn something)]
    pub type Something<T> = StorageValue<_, u32>;

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn labels)]
    pub(super) type Labels<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
        _,
        Twox64Concat,
        AccountOf<T>,
        Twox64Concat,
        HashId<T>,
        LabelsDetail<T>,
        OptionQuery,
    >;

    // Pallets use events to inform users when important changes are made.
    // https://docs.substrate.io/main-docs/build/events-errors/
    #[pallet::event]
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {
        /// Event documentation should end with an array that provides descriptive names for event
        /// parameters. [something, who]
        SomethingStored { something: u32, who: T::AccountId },
    }

    // Errors inform users that something went wrong.
    #[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
        /// Error names should be descriptive.
        NoneValue,
        /// Errors should have helpful documentation associated with them.
        StorageOverflow,
    }

    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::call_index(0)]
        #[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1).ref_time())]
        pub fn register_labels(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            info: RegisterInputLabelInfo,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let owner = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            let label_id: HashId<T> = T::Hashing::hash_of(&info.label_name);
            Ok(())
        }

        #[pallet::call_index(1)]
        #[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().reads_writes(1,1).ref_time())]
        pub fn cause_error(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult {
            let _who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            // Read a value from storage.
            match <Something<T>>::get() {
                // Return an error if the value has not been set.
                None => return Err(Error::<T>::NoneValue.into()),
                Some(old) => {
                    let new = old.checked_add(1).ok_or(Error::<T>::StorageOverflow)?;
                    <Something<T>>::put(new);
                    Ok(())
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Types.rs :`

```
use super::*;

pub mod Types {

    pub use crate::{
        pallet::Config,
        structs::{
            artist::Artist::ArtistInfo,
            labels::Labels::{LabelInfo, OperationalContact},
        },
    };
    use frame_support::traits::Currency;
    use frame_system::Config as SystemConfig;

    pub type BalanceOf<T> =
        <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance;

    pub type HashId<T> = <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash;

    pub type AccountOf<T> = <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId;

    pub type LabelsDetail<T> = LabelInfo<T>;

    pub type ArtistInfoDetail<T> = ArtistInfo<AccountOf<T>>;
}
```

`Labels.rs:`

```
use codec::{Decode, Encode, MaxEncodedLen};
use frame_support::{inherent::Vec, traits::ConstU32, BoundedVec};
use scale_info::TypeInfo;
use sp_runtime::RuntimeDebug;

pub mod Labels {
    use super::*;

    #[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
    pub struct LabelInfo<T: crate::Config> {
        pub owner: T::AccountId,
        pub label_id: T::Hashing,
        pub label_name: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<128>>,
    }
}
```

i faced this error and i dont know how can i sovle this problem .

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `LabelInfo<T>: parity_scale_codec::Decode` is not satisfied
> --> /root/Pikamo_Chain/frame/lib.rs:72:15
> |
> 72  |     #[pallet::storage]
> |               ^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::Decode` is not implemented for `LabelInfo<T>`

> #[pallet::storage]
> |               ^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::Decode` is not implemented for `LabelInfo<T>`

Comment: You can use [`#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/what-is-the-role-of-scale-infoskip-type-paramst)

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas still it show me this error : `#[pallet::storage]    
      |               ^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::Encode` is not implemented for `LabelInfo<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of providing a generic `T: Config` to your struct you can also provide generics for your fields:

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
pub struct LabelInfo<AccountId, Hashing> {
    pub owner: AccountId,
    pub label_id: Hashing,
    pub label_name: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<128>>,
}
```

My reasoning: when bounding your generic argument to your pallet's `Config` trait, rust macros want this `Config` to have all those traits implemented.

Now you are not using the pallet's `Config` in any way and declaring the fields of the struct as generic. In your pallet's code you will define those fields with `Config::AccountId` which implements those necessary traits.